# JPA spec JPQL production rule possible error?

Tags: jpa, jpql

JPA spec on JPQL:

```
single_valued_path_expression ::=
    qualified_identification_variable |
    TREAT(qualified_identification_variable AS subtype) |
    state_field_path_expression |
    single_valued_object_path_expression
```

qualified_identification_variable should be general_identification_variable in the rule above. Is this an error?

```
qualified_identification_variable :: =
    map_field_identification_variable |
    ENTRY(identification_variable)

general_identification_variable ::=
    identification_variable |
    map_field_identification_variable
```

Comment: Where did you find this Spec?

Comment: jpa specification 2.2